# proof explanation

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone  please  explain  these  steps  to  me .? The  notations  $\phi_{B,C}(e_i)$  and  then  $\phi_C\phi^{-1}_B[b_i]_B$  are  confusing  me .

[image: en ter image description here]

Comment: how does it confuse you? What is it you know? What are the steps and reasoning you have up to that point that makes you understand it? This information helps us locate your issue in your thought processes

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\phi_B$ ans $\phi_C$ are the linear transformation from the standard basis to the basis $B$ and $C$, i.e the matrices that have as columns the vectors of the basis $B$ and $C$. So, if $b_B=[b_i]_B$ is a vector expressed in the base $B$, $\phi^{-1} b$ is the same vector in the standard basis and $ \phi_{BC}=\phi_C(\phi^{-1} b)$ gives tne same vector in the basis $C$.

I hope that this can solve your problem.